# 'php' não reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo

Tags: php, sublime-text-3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estou me deparando com esse erro **ao salvar o arquivo**

Comment: Talvez você esteja usando algum tipo de linter (verifica erros de código), muitos deles tomam *trigger* quando salva, e você não tem o PHP nas suas variáveis de ambiente.

Comment: @Pliavi e como mudo isso?

Comment: Hm, pra isso precisaria que me respondesse 2 coisas (na verdade só a segunda, mas pra poder dar uma resposta mais completa a primeira é uma boa), quais plugins você usa que são relacionados ao PHP? e onde está a instalação do seu PHP (Seja via XAMPP, WAMP, Direto, etc)

Comment: uso php direto, uso plugins php apenas de auto complete...

Comment: Certo, qual o caminho da instalação? Qual o nome do plugin e qual o editor que está usando?

Comment: php snipets, uso sublime 3, caminho de instalação vc se refere ao php? pq eu estou apenas quardando o os arquivos na maquina, eu os rodo num servidor externo, o estranhissimo é que realmente do nada começou a dar esse erro, alguns minutos antes do erro fiquei sem internet

Comment: vou ver o que ha de errado aqui, obrigado pela ajuda..

Comment: Ah sim, não é algo normal, só conheço um plugin de "snippet" que utiliza o PHP (PHP-Intellisense do VSCode), acabei de ver as configs desse que você falou e ele só usa o que digita, sem verificar nada. Como o PHP não está instalado na sua máquina, ainda deve ter algum outro plugin procurando ele, vá desabilitando um a um e salvando, uma hora deve parar e você descobrirá qual o causador do problema. E se encontrar a solução, não hesite em responder sua própria pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Causador

De acordo com os comentários e a resposta anterior dada pelo próprio autor da pergunta
pode se perceber que o causador do problema é uma espécie de *[linter](https://willianjusten.com.br/analisando-seu-codigo-js-com-linter/)* que 
utiliza o executável *php* para verificar os problemas dentro do seu código, a maioria deles fazem isso
para se manterem consistentes em qualquer versão do moto utilizado, executando seu código e capturando os erros.

## Problema

Como a maioria dos *Linters* (e Syntax Chekers, Coding Standards Fixers, Style Checkers, etc) utilizam de algum executável
para fazer seus testes, os mesmos percisam estar instalados para que eles funcionem, como informado na resposta anterior, o problema
foi causado pelo [***PHP Syntax Checker***](https://github.com/naomichi-y/php_syntax_checker) da Naomichi-y, e percebe-se na [linha 6 do código do *checker*](https://github.com/naomichi-y/php_syntax_checker/blob/master/phpSyntaxChecker.py#L6) no GitHub que ela usa um comando do PHP:

```
...
EXECUTE_COMMAND = "php -l"
...
```

Esse comando é utilizado para verificação de erros no código APENAS como pode ser visto no [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php):

> `-l               Syntax check only (lint)`

Este comando só é executado caso o executável do php exista no seu computador e esteja mencionado nas suas variáveis de ambiente.

## Como Resolver

Existem 2 opções:

- ### Instalar o PHP

  **Oops:** Caso mesmo após instalado o problema persista, verifique se suas variáveis de ambiente estão levando até a pasta que contém o `php.exe`, caso não saiba como fazer, pode seguir [este passo-a-passo](https://www.webdevbr.com.br/fazendo-o-php-funcionar-no-console-cmd-do-windows-instalando-o-composer-e-o-git).
- ### Remover o Plugin

  **Oops:** Caso mesmo após removido o problema persista, verifique seus plugins, deve have mais algum que utilize o php, são raros, mas alguns autocompletes também podem utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

cabeça fria pensa melhor, eu estava com um plugin no sublime text 3 'PHP Syntax Checker' que havia intalado ha alguns dias e não lembrava. Eu o removi e o erro **não** voltou a aparecer.